# How to be able to use ToInt method in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code

```
Int32 clientiid = row["CodCliente "].ToInt();
```

but this is marked up as an error telling and you missing an directive or a reference 
What should I add to make ToInt work? 
I have used this references. Thank you in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;


Int32 clientiid = row["CodCliente "].ToInt();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what made you think there was a ".ToInt()" method intrinsic to object?

Comment: IF ToString() existed I thought why not ToInt() does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `ToInt()` method in C#.

If you have a boxed `int` value in an expression of type `object`, you can simply cast it:

```
int clientId = (int)row["CodCliente"];
```

If you aren't sure what the runtime type of the expression is (eg, if it might be `long` or `decimal`, or even a `string`), you can call `Convert.ToInt32()`, which will figure out what it actually is and then convert it to an `int` for you.

For more information, see [this excellent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).

Comment: Can you help me with this one too please  {DataTable dt = SqlClientiDataSet.Tables["ClientiImporti"];
                int clientiid;
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    clientiid = (int)row["Co "];
                    string emri = row["No "].ToString();
                    string piva = row["P "].ToString();
                    string cf = row["C "].ToString();
                }
                                int id= clientiid;//in this declaration I get and error it tells use of unassinged local varialbe. What's wrong with it

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand? Hint: What if there are no rows? You probably shouldn't be using a loop.

Comment: In fact there are colums named Co, No, P, C in a table. Does this rows take the elements of the columns. I am a newbie and this is the first time I use C#. With this code I want to grab the columns. In the code I sent you I changed the ) of the for each and placed it it in the end and this unmarked me the error I was getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following method,

```
Convert.ToInt32(row["CodCliente"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler tells you that it can't recognize `.ToInt()` method. So it should be declared or assembly with such method should be referenced in a header of document.

You can write something like this(extension method based on return type of row's data); if `row["index"]` returns string, for example:

```
public static int ToInt(this string number)
{
    return int.Parse(number);
}
```

Comment: C# does not have headers or documents.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method wrong. You need to do (assuming the value is a string) `Convert.ToInt32(row["CodCliente "])`

Also you can cast like this `(int)row["CodCliente "]` which I prefer.

Comment: @SLaks I didn't say they were :p I just said I prefer casting like that. There are obviously many options that will have different results depending on the data you're trying to cast/convert.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Object.ToInt()` method. You need to use either:

```
Convert.ToInt32(row["CodCliente "]);
```

Or

```
int.Parse(row["CodCliente "]);
```

Or, if the value is already an int in the row, you could simply just cast:

```
(int)row["CodeCliente "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use convert as such:

```
int clientId = Convert.ToInt32(row["CodCliente"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What date type is `row`? What data type does the indexer `row[string index]` return? Does that type have a `ToInt()` method? Is there an extension method `ToInt()` available for that type?

Is the class or struct castable to int (e.g., does `row["foo"] is int` return true? If so you can simply cast it, thus: `int x = (int) row["foo"]`.

If object is a string, you can use `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`.